# Android Studio 3.6.1 and Gradle build issues

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I've just updated to Android Studio and Gradle to 3.6.1; now, a library I've been using without problems until the last update is suddently removed by ProGuard (disabling ProGuard solves the issue).

The error from the logcat is:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: f.a.a.a.a.y.a: Provider org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModuleFactory not found
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModuleFactory
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModuleFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.debug-XwmJXio1aOq4FgKH-GjO6g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.debug-XwmJXio1aOq4FgKH-GjO6g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

I tried the following:

- Disabling proguard (e.i. commenting `//minifyEnabled true` & `//shrinkResources true`; this works, but I don't want it disabled in production.
- Adding `-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client** { *; }` or `-keepclasseswithmembers class org.eclipse.paho.** {*;}` or `-keep class * implements org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.spi.NetworkModuleFactory` to `proguard-rules.pro`; doesn't work.

Since I'm not familiar with proguard and how it manages external libraries, I'd appreciate any help or suggestion. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you try adding following rules:

-keep class class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.* { *; }
-keep class class org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*$* { *; }

Source: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/190

Comment: It doesn't work. Anyway, should't  `-keep class org.eclipse.paho.client.** { *; }` keep the subclasses too?

Comment: Hi, Did you resolved this issue? I am also facing same issue